# How to create a method in a binary tree structure to get the parent number of a node

Tags: java, data-structures

Here in my binary tree data structure:

```
//Every node has value and index
class Node<T> {
    Node<T> left,right;
    int index;
    T value;
    
    Node(T value, int index){
        this.index = index;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

class Tree<T> {
    int depth;
    Node<T> root;
    
    //Create an empty binary tree
    private static Tree<Object> empty = new Tree<>();
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <K> Tree<K> empty(){
        return (Tree<K>) Tree.empty;
    }
    
    //creating a binary tree by taking depth as input
    public static <K> Tree<K> depth(int deepest){
      if(deepest > 0) {
          Tree<K> tree =  Tree.empty();
          tree.root = new Node<>(null,0);
          tree.addLevel(tree.root, 0, deepest, 0);
          return tree;
       } 
      else {
          throw new Error();
       }
    }
    
    private void addLevel(Node<T> node, int depth, int deepest,int index){
        if (depth == deepest - 1) {
                return;
            } else {
        node.left = new Node<>(node.value,index*2+1);
        node.right = new Node<>(node.value,index*2+2);
        addLevel(node.left,depth+1,deepest, index*2+1);
        addLevel(node.right,depth+1,deepest,index*2+2);
        }
    }
    
    public void getAllElem(Node<T> node, List<HashMap<T,Integer>> list) {
        if (node == null) {
            return;
        } 
        else {
        HashMap<T, Integer> pairs = new HashMap<T, Integer>();
        getAllElem(node.left,list);
        pairs.put(node.value, node.index);
        list.add(pairs);
        getAllElem(node.right,list);        
    }}
```

In that case, I want to create a method **getParent(int index)**, when the user pass the index number to the method, it will return the value of the parent node.
For example, when the inputted index = 3, it will get the value of node(index = 1).
But I don't have any clue about how to do that, any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A naive algorithm would be to from the *parent* node check the leaf indices and return the *parent* value as soon as one has found the desired leaf index, namely:

```
T getParent(int index, Node<T> node){
     if(node == null)
        return null;
     else if(node.left != null && node.left.index == index  || node.right != null && node.right.index == index)
         return node.value;
     else{
         T value = getParent(index, node.left);
         return (value != null) ? value : getParent(index, node.right);
    }
}
```

This algorithm would have a time-complexity in the worst-case scenario of `N`, so pretty inefficient. One could, however, try to improve it to `O(log2N)`, if one would search only on the right or left leaf depending on the current *parent* index. For that one needs to find an expression that will let one knows which leaf to continue the search.

The most efficient algorithm for this problem takes `O(1)`. Since for a given node with index `n`, their leaves will be at the indices `2n + 1` and `2n + 2`, so you can make a small table and try to figure out the formula (that based on the leaf index returns the *parent* index):

```
index | parent 
0     | no parent 
1     | 0
2     | 0
3     | 1
4     | 1
5     | 2
6     | 2
7     | 3
8     | 3
9     | 4
10    | 4
```

Based on that table, one can infer that code-wise, one can obtain the parent index using the formula `(i-1)/2` with `i > 0`, and `i` begin the index of the leaf that one is looking for:

```
i = 2 -> (2-1)/2 = 0  (the value will be rounded down)
i = 3 -> (3-1)/2 = 1
i = 4 -> (4-1)/2 = 1 (the value will be rounded down)
....
i = 10 -> (10-1)/2 = 4  (the value will be rounded down)
```

so the code would be something as straightforward as :

```
int getParentIndex(int index){
    return (index == 0) ? -1 : (index - 1) / 2;
}
```

However, for this algorithm to work, you need to have an additional structure that stores the nodes by indices, so that you can access their values in `O(1)`. For instance, using an ArrayList:

```
private static List<Node<T>> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
```

When you add a node to your tree, you also added to that list. Then with the `getParentIndex` method you can access that index in the list, and retrieve the Node value.

This is the typical approach used on a [Binary Heap](http://%20https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap).